# Cannot run webpack-dev-server inside docker

Tags: docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have created a docker image which serves a simple react app using webpack from inside the container, but I get nothing in the browser.

Here are my config files

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "invas_client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --inline --content-base ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' }
        ]
    }
}
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# Use starter image
FROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose port
EXPOSE 8080

# Default command to run
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### What's working fine

When I run `npm start`, the `webpack-dev-server` runs normally, and when I go to http://localhost:8080, I see my page.

### What isn't working

When I run my server using docker, with the following command:

`docker build -t anubhav756/app . && docker run -p 80:8080 anubhav756/app`

the logs show everything working normally from inside the container, but when I point my browser to http://localhost, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Sample code's over **[here](https://github.com/anubhav756/webpack-docker)**

Comment: Are you running Docker natively on Linux, or in a VM with Docker Machine? If it's a VM then your container port is published inside the VM, so you need to browse to its IP address - `docker-machine ip`.

Comment: @EltonStoneman natively on Linux

Comment: Hmm. Anything interesting in the Docker chain from `iptables -L`?

Comment: `docker ps` shows this:
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
c25001e81847        anubhav756/invas_client   "npm start"         16 seconds ago      Up 14 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   berserk_hoover

Comment: `iptables -L` shows: 
Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere                
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Comment: All looks OK. Try a GET from inside the container to check the app is responding? `docker exec -it c25 bash` then `curl http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Got this: root@c25001e81847:/usr/src/app# curl http://localhost:8080
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <meta charset=utf-8/>
 <title>React</title>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>

Comment: @EltonStoneman looks fine from inside the container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123925/discussion-between-anubhav-dhawan-and-elton-stoneman).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You are actualy listening on localhost only.
To be reachable from outside replace the following line in your package.json file:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base ."
```

by :

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --inline --content-base ."
```

Related discussion : https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/147

Comment: Thanks mate. That solved it right away! You've got a keen eye

Comment: It's only solution if the page is served by server too. Otherwise u'll have websocket requests on your base domain which is not what you want.

Comment: This worked for me but for some reason I get a black page

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add something to Raphayol answer if you couldn't enable hot-reloading of webpack-dev-server inside container.
I couldn't make webpack or webpack-dev-server watch (--watch) mode work even after mounting my project folder into container.
To fix this you need to understand how webpack detects file changes within a directory.
It uses one of 2 softwares that add OS level support for watching for file changes called inotify and fsevent. Standard Docker images usually don't have these (specially inotify for linux) preinstalled so you have to install it in your Dockerfile.
Look for inotify-tools package in your distro's package manager and install it. fortunately all alpine, debian, centos have this.

Answer (score 4):

When using webpack-dev-server with [Encore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@symfony/webpack-encore) and exposing it through Docker, you we'll need to use `--host 0.0.0.0` **and** `--public localhost:8080` so files are served even on browsers [not navigating to 0.0.0.0 adresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565334/what-does-chrome-server-do-when-i-use-0-0-0-0-instead-of-localhost-in-browser).

Here is what I used :

```
webpack-dev-server --hot --host=0.0.0.0 --public=localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

to complement what Hugo H said, for me i had to do the following to let encore dev-server working fine on docker in a distant server where dev-server running on a declared adresse:

1 ) in webpack.config.js:

```
.configureDevServerOptions(options => {
    options.allowedHosts = 'all';
    options.host = '0.0.0.0';

    options.client       = {
        webSocketURL: 'https://encore-webserver.domain/ws'
    };
})
```

2. in package.json:

```
"dev-server": "encore dev-server --public https://encore-webserver.domain --port 80 ",
```

where `encore-webserver.domain` point with to a node docker container exposing port 80 who simply run `npm run dev-server`

this pages helped me to solve my problem:

- [symfony encore documentation (using virtual machines)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/virtual-machine.html)
- [symfony encore git issue that is still open on writting this message](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/951)