# What does Chrome/server do when I use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, ip

I am having a single page application running in webpack dev server for hot reloading on my local. However, the backend application of it was not on my local, it was host in a remote server, say `http://remote-server.com.`

When I use such address in the chrome address field: `0.0.0.0:3000/homepage`, the http request (api calls to remote backend server) was 5 times (even more) slower than using `localhost:3000/homepage`

I am really confused why would this happen?

Actually, more precisely, the question would be, what does it mean to a browser/server when I ask Chrome to ping 0.0.0.0, given the fact that 0.0.0.0 is simply used to say 'bind to any possible address'

The http requests are like

```
get /remote-server.com/api/v1/users
get /remote-server.com/api/v1/products
get /remote-server.com/api/v1/prices
```

I was expecting the http requests takes the same amount of time.. when I use `0.0.0.0` and `localhost`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*what does it mean to a browser/server when I ask Chrome to ping 0.0.0.0, given the fact that 0.0.0.0 is simply used to say 'bind to any possible address'*?

By specification [RFC5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-3.2.1.3), `0.0.0.0` only represents "source addresses", which means it is a non-routable address and cannot be used for destination.

However, **for practical reason, many client software treat `0.0.0.0` as `localhost`**. Such software list includes: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, curl, telnet etc. Because, as many web server software launch with messages like "listen on 0.0.0.0...", allow visiting to `0.0.0.0` is very user-friendly for junior developers.

Actually, for Chrome, this behavior was discussed as an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428046), the issue's status was "WontFix" at the beginning, but later changed to "Fixed" with following solution:

> Allow explicit navigations to "0.0.0.0" to support systems where this performs a
> navigation to localhost (in defiance of specs... but seemingly common).

> This still prevents navigation to any other IP with leading octet 0, and only
> allows 0.0.0.0 when it's actually entered in 4-component dotted-quad form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I am appreciated for it!