# How to handle redirection between docker container services?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to introduce docker for local development into an existing project.

I have two services **A** (previously being run on `localhost:5000`) & **B** (previously being run on  `localhost:5001`). **A** is a login application whereas **B** is the main application. **A** takes the username/password from the user, validates credentials & if valid, redirects the user to appropriate service B's entry point i.e. `localhost:5001/<user_role>` from where application **B** takes over.

When running without docker, this redirection between services works fine. But when using docker and running the projects, this redirection breaks (except when I use `host` network driver). I can access service **A**, login successfully but when the redirection happens, the browser's address bar shows the redirected entry point of service **B** and the browser says "The site can't be reached" and the request fails.

Here are my docker files:

**Service A**

Run as: `docker run -p 5000:5000 --name service_a_1 service_a`

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /home/node/serviceA
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

**Service B**

Run as: `docker run -p 5001:5001 --name service_b_1 service_b`

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /home/node/serviceB
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 5001
```

**But** when I use `--network=host` when running these containers, the redirection works fine but it fails with a `bridge` network driver. I have done my research going through the docker's documentation on networking and some tutorials on docker networking.

**Questions:**

1. Can the behavior that I want be achieved using `bridge` network?
2. Why is it not working for `bridge` network driver but works on `host`?

Comment: What is the contents of your `docker-compose` file? I use networking in my docker-compose file and all containers in the same `bridge` network can ping each other.

Comment: @Saeed I"m trying to do this without `docker-compose` first. But anyway, docker itself attaches the containers to `bridge` network by default. I don't think we need `docker-compose` for that. If I go into `serviceA` and ping `serviceB` with B's IP address, the ping does go through.

Comment: @Saeed, Thanks for your interest. I've found the solution to my problem & I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [Cannot run webpack-dev-server inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632038/cannot-run-webpack-dev-server-inside-docker) after some additional research. This solved my issue.

Additional resources:

- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/147